# Windows Scripting: Registry Import from Pipe/STDIN?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, registry, pipe

Is it possible to import registry entries directly from the output of another process (i.e. over a pipe from STDIN)?

I have some registry entries in a .reg file that I'd like to import, but only after making some on-the-fly modifications (filling in placeholder values like username, etc.). I was planning on using the methods from [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034) to do the modifications, but now I need to figure out how to get the modified version into the registry.

```
(gc foo.reg) -creplace '^"UserName"=""$', "`"UserName`"=`"$env:USERNAME`"" | | ...
```

I've been looking at the documentation for `REG IMPORT`, which requires a filename as an arguments. In Unix shell-scripting, which I have much more experience in, there are a lot of ways to solve the problem. If we imagine a Unix version of the command `reg -i` which requires a filename, some possible solutions would be

```
sed 's/bar/baz/' foo.reg|reg -i
```

or

```
sed 's/bar/baz/' foo.reg|reg -i -
```

or

```
sed 's/bar/baz/' foo.reg|reg -i /dev/stdin
```

or even

```
reg -i <(sed 's/bar/baz/' foo.reg)
```

(Only the first two are at all natural.)

Is there an equivalent for Windows?

Note that I'm fine with solutions in either CMD- or PowerShell-style scripting, if that makes a difference.

Comment: A few alternatives: I'm fairly sure you can modify the registry directly from PowerShell; or you could use `reg add`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reg import` expects a filename and not stdin AFAICT from its help.  So I would read the original .reg file and modify the contents, save that to a new file and import that new file:

```
(Get-Content foo.reg) -replace '^("UserName"\s*=\s*")"$', "`$1$env:UserName`"" > modfoo.reg
reg import modfoo.reg
```

Comment: Apparently this is the best possible. Thanks!